# Latex does not show my reference in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I do not klnow why I am using bibliography but I cannot see the reference both in the text and in the section Reference. Here the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{moreverb,url}

\newcommand\BibTeX{{\rmfamily B\kern-.05em 
\textsc{i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\volumeyear{2016}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}
\cite{Mayer}, \cite{Oca} and \cite{IEA}

\section{Reference}

\bibliographystyle{SageH}
\bibliography{my_bibtex2}



\end{document}
```

Here below my bblatex

```
@article{Mayer,
title = "User behaviour regarding natural 
ventilation – state of the art and
research needs",
journal = "9th Nordic Symposium on Building 
Physics - NSB 2011",
volume = "3",
author = "Mayer"
}


@article{Oca,
title = "Effect of thermostat and window opening 
occupant behavior models on energy use in 
homes",
journal = "Building Simulation",
author = "Oca"
}

@article{IEA,
title =   " Reliability of Energy Efficient 
Building Retrofitting-",
author = "IEA"
}
```

In the same folder of the script file I have SageH.bst

I cannot understand why I jusrt get question mark and the bibliography does not appear.

Any idea?

Comment: you need `\cite` not `\ref` to reference the bib items.

Comment: Unrelated but please also double check the entries in your bib file. In all of them, at least the `author` and `year` fields are missing.

Comment: Hi, yes sorry I correct them but I still have the same problem

Comment: now you have changed the question as your example is using `\cite` so the standard answer will apply, run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex twice more and you should have a bibliography.

Comment: You wrote, "I cannot understand why I jusrt get question mark and the bibliography does not appear." There are likely two, separate reasons: (i) Failure to run BibTeX, and (ii) problems with the bibtex file. E.g., Is the bibtex file called `my_bibtex2.bib` or just `my_bibtex2`?

Comment: Incidentally, the `@article` entry type appears to be inappropriate for two of the three entries. The `@article` entry type should be used *exclusively* for pieces published in scholarly journals. When in doubt, use the catch-all `@misc` entry type.

Comment: my_bibtex2   I think I messed up in the configuration of  Textmaker. If you go to option, configure texmaker at the option Bib(la)Tex. Which type of address should I have to type?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve never used TeXmaker.